# How to use "or " operator to assign several values to a variable?

Tags: perl

I'm new with perl.

I would like to say that a variable could take 2 values, then I call it from another function.

I tried:

```
  my(@file) = <${dirname}/*.txt || ${dirname}/*.xml> ;
```

but this seems not working for the second value, any suggestions?

Comment: `glob "$dirname/..."` is buggy. It fails for directories with spaces in them, for example.

Comment: `<${dirname}/*.txt>, <${dirname}/*.xml>` can also be written as `<${dirname}/*.{txt,xml}>`

Answer (score 6):

When using the `<*>` operator as a fileglob operator, you can use any common glob pattern. Available patterns are

- `*` (any number of any characters),
- `?` (any single character),
- `{a,b,c}` (any of the `a`, `b` or `c` patterns),

So you could do

```
my @file = glob "$dirname/*.{txt,xml}";
```

or

```
my @file = (glob("$dirname/*.txt"), glob("$dirname/*.xml"));
```

or

```
my @file = glob "$dirname/*.txt $dirname/*.xml";
```

as the glob pattern is split at whitespace into subpatterns

Comment: maybe OP want to use anonymous array or hash for task? `my @file = ([(glob( "$dirname/*.txt"))],[(glob("$dirname/*.xml"))])`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want `@files` to fallback on the second option (`*.xml`) if no `*.txt` files are found.

If so, your syntax is close. It should be:

```
my @files = <$dirname/*.txt> || <$dirname/*.xml>;
```

or

```
my @files = glob( "$dirname/*.txt" ) || glob( "$dirname/*.xml" );
```

Also, it's a good idea to check for `@files` to make sure it's populated (what if you don't have any `*.txt` or `*.xml`?)

```
warn 'No @files' unless @files;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my(@file) = <${dirname}/*.txt>, <${dirname}/*.xml> ;
```

<> converts it into an array of file names, so you are essentially doing my @file = @array1, @array2. This will iterate first through txt files and then through xml files.

Answer (score 0):

```
my (@file) = (<${dirname}/*.txt>, <${dirname}/*.xml>);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
my $file = $val1 || $val2;
```

what it means is set $file to $val1, but if $val1 is 0 or false or undef then set $file1 to $val2

In essence, surrounding a variable with `< >` means either

1) treat it as a filehandle ( for example `$read=<$filehandle>` )

2) use it as a shell glob  (for example `@files=<*.xml>` )

Looks to me like you wish to interpolate the value $dirname and add either .txt or .xml on the end.  The < > will not achieve this

If you wish to send two values to a function then this might be what you want

```
my @file=("$dirname.txt","$dirname.xml");
```

then call the function with @file, ie `myfunction(@file)`

In the function

```
sub myfunction {
  my $file1=shift;
  my $file2=shift;
```

All this stuff is covered in perldocs perlsub and perldata

Have fun